# How to center a canvas on top of a background image

Tags: css, html, canvas

I have an image that I want to use as a document background, and place on top of it a canvas element.

The reason is that the background is large (2048x1024) and if I place it inside the canvas it will be redrawn on every frame wasting resources.

```
<div id="container">
    <image class = "img1" src = "./assets/game.jpg" id= "backk"/>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1366" height="1024">No Canvas support!</canvas>    
</div>

        container {         
        position: relative;
        width:100%;
            margin : auto;

        }
    canvas{
        display:block;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index:1;
        }
    img1{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index:0;          
    }
```

Using the above markup, what should my CSS be in order to get the result seen also in the following picture:

[image]

Comment: What CSS have you tried?

Comment: Sorry missed the CSS somehow... :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with absolute positions:

```css
#container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 350px; height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}
#container .img1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px; height: 250px;
}
#container #canvas {
  position: absolute;
  outline: 2px solid black;
  top: 10px; left: 60px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="container">
      <image class="img1" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=FF6347&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Image-1&w=350&h=250" id="back"/>
      <canvas id="canvas" width="250" height="250">No Canvas support!</canvas></div>
```

You can also achieve this without absolute positions using `margin: 0 auto`,
or `display: inline-block` and `text-align:center`, or with flex positions, or with `transform: translate(...)`

Ex:

```
#container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 350px; height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}
#container .img1 {
  display: block;
  width: 350px; height: 250px;
}
#container #canvas {
  outline: 2px solid black;
  transform: translate(50px, -250px);
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the solution without absolute positions? Because that is what i've been trying all day long with no luck..

Comment: Thanks, will try it out and get back as soon as possible!

Comment: Wow, i really don't get CSS... Anyway your answer is correct, although my question was not exact. Thank you!

Comment: thx... css is actually focused on text ... it's properties work really well for newspaper or magazine format ... when you need to place thing on top of each other, center elements (specially vertical centering) or create custom grids, that's when css really get's in your way.