# How to cache static canvas areas in order to gain performance

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, easeljs, createjs

I am using createjs library, and my game has a large bitmap on the background, in order to fill a window in full HD resolution. In lower resolutions i use a pan and scan like method.  But the action is always limited in a smaller area of the canvas.

So i would like to know if it is possible, and how, to gain performance by caching static areas, or using any other technique.

For the sake of the argument here is a graph that demonstrates my situation :

[image: Can i cache the marked areas?]

I 've already tried to put the background image behind the canvas element using CSS here :

[How to center a canvas on top of a background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247078/how-to-center-a-canvas-on-top-of-a-background-image)

But CSS is driving me insane...so please bear with me...
:)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EaselJS every `DisplayObject` has a cache method, which is exactly doing what you want - it takes the painted stuff and puts in on a off-screen Canvas: http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/DisplayObject.html
Afterwards it takes the image-data from the off-canvas for every repaint (basically it's just a drawImage call afterwards).

Try to only cache painted areas - if you cache empty areas, you will lose performance. However if your background is just a static image you should still keep it as a normal DOM/CSS background - there isn't any performance benefit from caching a bitmap.

Comment: I 've been using DisplayObject.cache(), i just didn't know if it makes any sense caching my background bitmap. Thanks

Comment: Feel free to post your CSS-related question(s) - pretty sure we could help you with that. ;-)

Comment: As a workaround you could also create a own canvas just for the background and only paint that once or on change. ;-)

Comment: Thank you derz. Wouldn't a second canvas require the same CSS to be added on the background? I will edit my question as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same idea once, and I think what you are asking for is [getImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) and [putImageDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData)

```
image = context.getImageData(x,y,width,height);
context.putImageData(image,x,y);
```

However, I still found the performance of this to be very poor (sorry, I can't provide any actual numbers any more), and the best and also most popular way to achieve better performance seems to be to make a second canvas just for the background, or, if you really just have a static background image, use pure CSS like you originally wanted.

context.drawImage() can also draw from another canvas element, maybe you can utilise this in some way and create inivisible "canvas caches". But I still think that it's easier to learn CSS than implement something like this.

Comment: Thanks for the info, seems like i will have to use CSS... :(

Comment: Caches in EaselJS are off-screen canvases. Once you cache an object, it is stored, and drawn in place of the actual contents.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familear with createjs, but you can try to draw / clear only on active area. This way you will not redraw inactive areas with each frame.
if inactive areas are not completely static, you can use separate canvas elements for them, and draw those on the main canvas once something have changed on that area (inactive area). I ho